# Wear pattern on tire

Tags: tires

[image]

What causes this "shredded" wear on the shoulder of both left tires (displayed is the front tire, 1 year old, ~20KKM)?

The wear on the thread area is regular, alignment was done, pressure is fine.
The vehicle in question is a LHD Opel Astra H Caravan (no modifications). I drive mixed (1/2 highway, the rest is urban and mountain road).

The tires on the right side do not have this pattern.

[image]

Comment: What is the vehicle in question? How many miles (kms) on the tires? Is it right or left hand drive?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 added additional information

Answer (score 1):

Do you drive on the left or right? if on the right, then these are the tires that "scrub" the outer edges when you go round roundabouts, which does tend to hack at the edges when a bit of speed is involved.

Comment: @Martin re read please, I got left and right swapped as I was thinking it through...

Comment: Is that a regular occurence? The tire shops in my area are clueless (as usual, about everything)

Comment: If you go round a lot of roundabouts... but if you are mostly on the autoroute, motorway less so.

Comment: @SolarMike I believe you were right the first time - in a country that drives on the left of the road roundabouts are a clockwise direction so the left tyres are the loaded outside tyres. Unless you meant whether the steering wheel was on the left or right!